# colored citation inside caption of figure leads to crash

Tags: hyperref, captions

I use the command

```
\newcommand{\redcite}[1]{{\hypersetup{citecolor=red}\cite{#1}}}
```

to give a red color to certain citation. If used inside a caption of a figure, the *pdflatex* process crashes with

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].

How can I prevent this to happen?

Comment: you didn't provide a complete example so one can't test, but my first try would be to use \protect\redcite

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: This solves the problem. Can you explain why it is necessary to put \protect in front?

Comment: the text of the citation moves into the list of figures and so should contain only robust commands. Fragile commands must be protected. You can also (with a current latex) define with `\NewDocumentCommand\redcite{m}{ ....}`. The \redcite is then directly robust.